# swift observer does not work

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, observers, notificationcenter

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    print("addd observer")

}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification) {
    let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    print("show")
    if(activeTectField != Lable_title && keyboard_status == false)
    {

        boxview.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardSize?.height)!
        keyboard_status = true

    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification) {

    let keyboardSize = (sender.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    if(keyboard_status == true){
    boxview.frame.origin.y = 0
    boxview.layoutIfNeeded()
    keyboard_status = false
    }

}
```

I add observer to move view when keyboard pop up and it works at first but after few clicks, it doesn't work. In `viewWillAppear()`, observer was already added but keyboard didn't pop up and also `keyboardwillshow()` was not fired.  How can I solve this problem? Any advice is welcome

Comment: add whole view controller please

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the target/selector pattern, those methods have to be compatible with Objective-C.

Precede your keyboard methods with the `@objc` modifier.

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification) {
```